# How to use same controller for two identical views in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-seed

I'm working on Angular seed in my project.
I have two identical views(HTML pages) which are same (having same elements and functionality).
 These two pages have `GridView` that are to be populated by same service as well but only the REST API URL is different for both of these pages. Now in my router.js, I want to use `$stateprovider.state()` to route to these pages.
 My question is: Can I use a single controller for both these views or a separate controller for each. But, when I use the same controller for both view pages I get "Injector not defined" error.
Is there a different way to do it? What is the best procedure to handle such conditions?

Comment: can you provide some code? :)

Comment: You're using ui-router I gather?

Comment: you can wrap your grid into a directive (the directive could contain its own controller) then reuse this directive on your views

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a generic answer, I can update it if you provide some additional details or code. It's possible to use the same controller for different views. Although personally, I tend to try to avoid this, in case I later have to mod one of the views. I would use two different controllers, but put a lot of common code in a service/directives. I think it's a good practice to minimize the amount of business logic in your controllers.

If you have identical views, that only change an url, I would consider using an url parameter or route parameter for this. Then you would in reality only have one view and one controller.